# Nested ISNUMBER SEARCH functions, if more than one returns as TRUE

Tags: microsoft-excel-365

The problem I have is that if Georgia appears in more than one classroom this string only shows the first occurrence, and I want it to show an error because she cannot be in 2 classrooms at once.  How do I make it show a FALSE/ERROR value when more than one ISNUMBER(SEARCH is TRUE?

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B5)),"6",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B16)),"7",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B27)),"8",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B38)),"10",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B49)),"11",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B60)),"12",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B71)),"1",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B82)),"2",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B93)),"3",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B104)),"14",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B1156)),"15",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B126)),"18",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B137)),"19",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B148)),"26",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B159)),"27",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B170)),"16",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B181)),"17",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B192)),"20",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Georgia",'[2024 Classroom Timetables.xlsx]Sheet 1'!B203)),"21","ERROR")))))))))))))))))))

Hoping someone can please help.

Comment: Do you know VBA?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Reformat you formula to return "1" for each time it finds "Georgia" and place a SUM() around it. Then check if the sum is greater than 1.